# How to convert address match formulas into dynamic ranges?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to develop a formula that sums cells in a column based on a range set dynamically by the addresses of two cells with specific text that change address depending on how many rows are between the two cells.

Example: sheet `red_fruit`

```
    |        A                        |        B   |      C
 1  |       Fruit store               |            |      
 2  |                                 |   apples   |      5
 3  |                                 |   apples   |      5
 4  |                                 |   oranges  |      1
 5  |  Fruit store branches (text)    |            |
```

In a second sheet called "summary", using the data from sheet "red_fruit" I want to add the amount of apples in column C based on a range set from row "fruit store" to row "fruit store branches" and ignore the amount of oranges.

However, I do not want to use absolute cell addresses (A1, B2, etc) because I know that the columns between "fruit store" and "fruit store branches" will change in future sheets.

I also need to constrain the C values to the depth of "fruit store branches" because I know that in the future there will be more data after that row.

In the past I have been able to do this with the following formula:

```
=SUMIF( 'red_fruit'!$B$1:B, "apples*", 'red_fruit'!$C$1:C )
```

But that only works for absolute values for the B column and it does not have dynamic limits neither for the B column nor for the C column.

So now I need to figure out a way to replace the B values with a dynamic formula that adjusts to automatically if I add more rows between "fruit store" and "fruit store branches".

I was able to get the address for column B dynamically using the following formulas:

For the "fruit store" row:

```
=ADDRESS((MATCH("fruit store",A1:A,1)),2,4)
```

The result is B1

For the "fruit store branches" row:

```
=ADDRESS((MATCH("fruit store branches",A1:A,1)),2,4)
```

The result iss B5

Here's where I got stuck. I have been unable to mix the formulas to create a dynamic range. The best I have been able to come up with this the following formula, but it returns an error:

```
=SUMIF( indirect"&(ADDRESS((MATCH("fruit store",A1:A,1)),2,4):"&(ADDRESS((MATCH("fruit store branches",A1:A,1)),2,4) , "apples*", c1:c ))
```

What I'm looking for would look like this:

```
=SUMIF( 'red_fruit'!dynamic_cell_address_formula1:'red_fruit'!dynamic_cell_address_formula2 , "apples", 'red_fruit'!$C$1:C )
```

Comment: you like those dynamic ranges dont you?

Comment: Is not that I like dynamic ranges. I need to use them in order to get specific results just by adding data. My bad on the excel tag. I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

`=sum(filter(red_fruit!C:C,row(red_fruit!C:C)<MATCH("fruit store branches",red_fruit!A1:A,1),red_fruit!B:B="apples"))`

Comment: Didn't work. I got a #REF! error. Also I think the formula should be defined not just by the rows before "fruit store branches", but also by the rows by the rows after "fruit store", as I will be applying the same formula many times to different sections of the data in the sheet. So there will be one section defined by "fruit store":"fruit store branches" and another by "juice bar":"juice bar branches".

Comment: have you tried adjusting the formula to fit your needs? Have you tried using just the Filter() part until it returns the rows you want?   
SO is a help site, not we-do-the-work-for-you...

Comment: Yes, I did adjust it and I still got an error. And no, I wasn't looking for somebody to solve it for me, as you can see from my own aswer to the problem using a transitional sheet and 3 formulas to create the range and then the final addition.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a solution to this problem with a single formula, but I was able to solve it using 3 formulas in a transitional sheet.

First, I created a sheet called "AppleData". In AppleData, cell B2, I entered the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("Fruit Store",'red_fruit'!$A$1:$A,0), "")
```

That would give me the first coordinate for the range from "fruit store" to "fruit store branches". If there is no data, then the IFERROR formula would simply leave the cell blank.

Then, in the cell below, B3, I entered this formula:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("*Fruit Store Branches*",'red_fruit'!$A$1:$A,0)-1, B2)
```

Again, if there was no data, the cell would match cell B2, which would be either blank, or with a valid coordinate number.

Next, in B4, I added a formula that used the contents of cells B2 and B3 to create the range between "Fruit Store" and "Frui Store Branches", look for "apples" and then add the quantities only for the apple entries :

```
=SUMIF( indirect("red_fruit!A"&AppleData!B2&":A"&AppleData!B3), "*apples*", indirect("red_fruit!C"&AppleData!B2&":C"&AppleData!B3) )
```

Then I created a similar system for each month of the year, as each month I would get a new spreadsheet with different data to sort and plug into a summary sheet.

So now all I have to do is go to a summary sheet and add up the "B4" cells, thus solving the problem of creating dynamic ranges for this scenario.

Personally, I would've prefer to use a single formula in the summary sheet, but since this also works and it solves the same problem, I can live with it.

Thanks to those of you who gave it a sincere shot at solving this problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention: This solution works fine for Google Spreadsheets and it works fine if you download the spreadsheet to Excel format. But it won't work if you open the .xlsx file it in Open Office 4.1, as Open Office 4.1 it does not handle the IFERROR formula. It will work in the latest version of Libre Office, though. I also noticed that for some reason Google Spreadsheet changes the A open value to A1024 for Excel. That might cause problems with the sheet but it can be solved with a find a replace from A1024 to A within the formula.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want =)

```
=SUMIFS(
OFFSET(red_fruit!$A$1,
MATCH("Fruit Store",red_fruit!$A:$A,),2,
MATCH("Fruit store branches (text)",red_fruit!$A:$A,),1),
OFFSET(red_fruit!$A$1,MATCH("Fruit Store",red_fruit!$A:$A,),1,
MATCH("Fruit store branches (text)",red_fruit!$A:$A,),1),"apples")
```